# Which stretchMode to use in GridView on android

Tags: android, layout, gridview

Following is my xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@+id/gridviewgallery"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:columnWidth="@dimen/gridview_column_width"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:verticalSpacing="0dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="#444444"
/>
```

When I use android:stretchMode="columnWidth" , it creates a gap between the columns(though it fills the screen width)
And if I use android:stretchMode="none" , it gets left aligned and there is a gap left on right side of screen(though now there is no gap between columns)
Problem is I want both : To fill the screen width as well no gap between columns.
How to achieve it?

Comment: Increase the number of columns.

Answer (score 17):

A combination of `android:numColumns="auto_fit"`  `android:stretchMode="columnWidth"`  and `android:columnWidth="60dp"`  will give you a layout that adjusts for different screen sizes. Much better than fixing the number of columns. See example below...

```
<GridView
        android:id="@+id/tablegrid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ffff7965"
        android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
        android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:columnWidth="60dp"
        />
```

Comment: I spent several days looking for this solution! Excellent!

Answer (score 6):

It's very simple dude, just remove the line

```
android:columnWidth="@dimen/gridview_column_width"
```

you can specify any number of columns, i am given number of column = 4

```
android:numColumns = "4"
```

This is working fine for me

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is a little old but here is an answer I found hoping this helps someone else, just for `android:stretchMode` use `spacingWidthUniform` as it says in documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html#attr_android:stretchMode) it will stretch the spacing between columns equally.

please refer to above link for more information.